# Scrapy FEEDS without headers in non default folder

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to save a data into a csv file via:

*>scrapy crawl spider_name -O ../output/file_name.csv*

in another folder than the default one when just using:

*>scrapy crawl spider_name -O file_name.csv*

however I also want to save the data without any headers.
I found that you could include:

```
FEEDS = {
    'file_name.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'include_headers_line': False,
        },
    }
}
```

into settings.py. That now raises the problem that '-O' doesn't replace the file anymore but instead appends when using the command multiple time and more importantly it doesn't work if I use:

```
FEEDS = {
    r'file:///D:\xyz\output\file_name.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'include_headers_line': False,
        },
    }
}
```

for my wanted target folder in Windows.

How do I ensure that the file gets replaced by a new one and that my data gets inserted right away without the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question you simply need to add `overwrite: True` to your `FEEDS` dictionary:

```
FEEDS = {
    'file_name.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'include_headers_line': False,
        },
        'overwrite': True,
    }
}
```

However I don't understand your problem with the command line args.  Specifying the storage backend in your settings eliminates the need to provide the `-O` command line arguments.

Your URI should work fine if you use forwardslashes instead of backslashes.

```
file:///D:/xyz/output/file_name.csv
```

Making these changes should force scrapy to overwrite the csv file for each execution and ignore adding headers to the file.

Comment: Thank you that did everything I wanted! I thought I had already tried the simple forwardslashes (I tried a lot) but maybe I made a mistake in the command line or something.